# How to deal with a long running API call in a WKWebView when switching to the background

Tags: ios, swift, wkwebview

We have an app that implements a custom payment method using WKWebView - which works fine when the app is active.

We have an issue which is causing payments to fail when the app goes into the background (the user switches apps or receives a phone call for example).

When the user returns to the app the payment transaction will have failed.

It seems the WKWebView's processing was paused and couldn't receive the response from the payment server.

I have tried to use UIApplication.shared.beginBackgroundTask to squeeze some more processing time into the app's execution when it is in the background but it doesn't seem to resolve the issue.

Any ideas?

Comment: If its the 100% case then better find a way to just cancel/reject that payment once your app enters background in `applicationDidEnterBackground`. If there is any pause/resume option for payment that could also be utilized.

Comment: @Kamran thanks for the suggestion, I'll see what the guys think.